# jQuery if element:contains Isn't Working

Tags: jquery

I have a site with code reminiscent to this code and I don't understand why the `if` statement isn't working. From looking at other code examples, my guess is that I need another function above my `if` statement? (instead of the `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`)

**HTML:**

```
<p>Paragraph One</p>
<p class="red">Target paragraph</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if($('p:contains("target")')){
    $(this).removeClass("red");
  }
)};
```

**jsFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/2a2qpg15/

**Worth Noting:** *Using `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` because it's a WordPress build.*

**edit:** *Leaving the lowercase version of `"target"` in here, but case sensitivity wasn't the only issue*

Any help, direction, and/or docs appreciated!

Comment: It's case sensitive. You need to search for "Target" http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Capitalizing "Target" alone didn't resolve the issue, but @KScandrett answer worked. Still unsure why the `if` statement doesn't work

Comment: It doesn't work because `this` doesn't refer to the jQuery object as you're expecting. To have it refer to the object you would need to use `$('p:contains("target")').each(function() { ... $(this) ... })`

Comment: It isn't a duplicate question IMO because fixing case-sensitivity alone won't resolve the OP's problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "target" to "Target" - it is case-sensitive and you could use this instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('p:contains("Target")').removeClass("red"); 
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m092Lxyn/

Answer (score 2):

Check length property since jQuery returns an object which is always truthy value in JavaScript. Although [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is case sensitive so use `Target` instead.

```
if($('p:contains("Target")').length)
```

---

For removing apply [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove) method directly on the `$('p:contains("Target")')` since `this` is not refers to the element.

```
$('p:contains("Target")').remove();
```

---

Or use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) method for case insensitive match.

```
$('p').filter(function(){ 
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf("target") > -1; 
}).remove()
```